# Query will not run with Variable

Tags: python, firebase-realtime-database, pyrebase

I have a Firebase Real-Time database that is setup using Python library Pyrebase. I am trying to query the database to find equal values. My issue is the query I am using does not return any values just empty brackets. Here is the query I am using to check for equal values `result = db.child("Users").order_by_child("Userid").equal_to( mUserID ).get()` . However, if `mUserID` is replaced with the actual value such as *O3tsfXJY8DXL52XF8PO65IAQFV* it works just fine and returns the correct user. I am not sure why the variable `mUserID` is not being accepted in the query. It is set properly and given a value. I have followed the Pyrebase Doc on querying for equal values and I cannot seem to spot any issues.

Below I have posted the code and the structure of the data base. Alse the `.onIndex` databases rules are provided.

```
 def database(mUserID):
        if mUserID:#If value is inputed
            print("Searching..")
                try:
                result = db.child("Users").order_by_child("Userid").equal_to( mUserID ).get()
                print(result.val(), "User Exist!")
            except ValueError:
                print("No Value given/stored")
```

[image]

```
    {
  "rules": {
    ".read": true,  
    ".write": true, 
      "Users": {
        ".indexOn" : ["Userid"]
      }
  }
}
```

Comment: In your code and in your rules you have `order_by_child("Userid")` and `["Userid"]`, but in your JSON/database it is spelled as `UserID`. The case is different between them, and Firebase is case sensitive. You'll want to make your rules and code match the casing in the JSON.

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen Thanks!  So I made the advised changes and I am still getting the same result. The variable will not be call in the query but the value will.